# Pages beyond the bounds of HorizontalPager never call onDispose | Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose, horizontal-pager

I've found strange behavior in [HorizontalPager](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/pager).

**Pages beyond the bounds never call `onDispose` inside `DisposableEffect`**. In other words, what kind of key `DisposableEffect` must consume in order to trigger `onDispose` once the page becomes "inactive"(stops composing)?

In my case, there are 5 pages of content for the pager. Using `beyondBoundsPageCount == 1` there are always 2-3 pages composed at the time, while others aren't.

The screen with pager:

```
...

HorizontalPager(
  pageCount = pages.size,
  state = pagerState,
  beyondBoundsPageCount = 1
) { index ->
  val page = pages[index]
  PageScreen(page, index)
}

...
```

The page itself:

```
@Composable
fun PageScreen(
  pageData: PageData,
  index: Int
) {

  DisposableEffect(key1 = Unit) { // What kind of key there must be
    Timber.d("DisposableEffect body at $index")

    onDispose {
      // The block which is never gets called
      Timber.d("DisposableEffect onDispose at $index")
    }
  }
}
```

P.S.:

Compose version is stable `1.4.1`

HorizontalPager is from `androidx.compose.foundation.pager.HorizontalPager`